# OpenGL : Cell division effect

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut, glm-math

I want to model the (biological) cell division process. I have been able to create a 3D cell model and load the model (using glm library). However, I do not know how to make it divide and I don't know where to start.

Does any one know how to make the effect that things replicate in OpenGL? (It is great if I can use glut and glm for that). Maybe you could just show me how to make a sphere replicate.

Comment: Draw two overlapping spheres and slowly move their center points apart?

Comment: If you're at the point where you don't know how to manipulate meshes, I would suggest changing what you want your project to be. Always pick a project that you know how to do, or won't particularly stretch your skills too far. What you're doing generally requires someone to go into a modelling package, generate an animation, and do various other stuff. It's very non-trivial, not if you want it to actually look good.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thanks, I'll try it and see the effect. (How didn't I come up with that?) I was trying tweening without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're [looking for](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgLJrvoX_qo) is called [meta-particles](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XBhkCYVkII) or [meta-balls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs). I think that by adjusting thresold function you can get cell-divide effect, but this isn't guaranteed - metaballs normally look more like quicksilver and are used to create water out of particles.

They're hard to implement in 3d for a novice - you'll need to be able to make triangular mesh out of mathematically-defined surface ([marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) algorithm), and result isn't guaranteed to be fully realistic.

I suggest to try something else or use some cheaper way - draw two seme-transparent spheres on top of each other then move them apart or something like that.

Of course, certain way to get desired result is to use modeling package (like blender) and skilled artist, but displaying modeled result in your application will be difficult, because object topology will be changing every frame, plus making satisfactory result will take time and skill.

Comment: I am trying your one of your suggestion: 'draw two seme-transparent spheres on top of each other then move them apart'. However, I'm having one problem with blending: the overlapping part has different color compared to other parts of the cell, which makes the process not very satisfactory.